# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am using the WOK Command Handler and it was working fine for a few commands, then it suddenly stopped working when I created a new command, then went backwards and deleted the command, and still got the same error meaning that the error is in this file.

It's giving the error for the `` console.log(`Registering the "${commands[0]}" command!`) `` snippet.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { prefix } = require('../config.json')

const validatePermissions = (permissions) => {
    const validPermissions = [
        'ADMINISTRATOR',
        'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE',
        'KICK_MEMBERS',
        'BAN_MEMBERS',
        'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
        'MANAGE_GUILD',
        'ADD_REACTIONS',
        'VIEW_AUDIT_LOG',
        'PRIORITY_SPEAKER',
        'STREAM',
        'VIEW_CHANNEL',
        'SEND_MESSAGES',
        'SEND_TTS_MESSAGES',
        'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
        'EMBED_LINKS',
        'ATTACH_FILES',
        'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
        'MENTION_EVERYONE',
        'USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS',
        'VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS',
        'CONNECT',
        'SPEAK',
        'MUTE_MEMBERS',
        'DEAFEN_MEMBERS',
        'MOVE_MEMBERS',
        'USE_VAD',
        'CHANGE_NICKNAME',
        'MANAGE_NICKNAMES',
        'MANAGE_ROLES',
        'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS',
        'MANAGE_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS',
        'USE_SLASH_COMMANDS',
        'REQUEST_TO_SPEAK',
        'MANAGE_THREADS',
        'USE_PUBLIC_THREADS',
        'USE_PRIVATE_THREADS',
        'USE_EXTERNAL_STICKERS',
    ]

    for (const permission of permissions) {
        if (!validPermissions.includes(permission)) {
            throw new Error(`Unknown permission node "${permission}"`)
        }
    }
}

const allCommands = {

}

module.exports = (commandOptions) => {
    let {
        commands,
        permissions = [],
    } = commandOptions

    if (typeof commands === 'string') {
        commands = [commands]
    }

    console.log(`Registering the "${commands[0]}" command!`)

    if (permissions.length) {
        if (typeof permissions === 'string') {
            permissions = [permissions]
        }

        validatePermissions(permissions)
    }

    for (const command of commands) {
        allCommands[command] = {
            ...commandOptions,
            commands,
            permissions
        };
    }
}

module.exports.listen = (client) => {
    client.on('message', (message) => {
        const { member, content, guild } = message;

        const arguments = content.split(/[ ]+/);
        const name = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();

        if (name.startsWith(prefix)) {
            const command = allCommands[name.replace(prefix, '')]
            if (!command) {
                return
            }

            const {
                permissions,
                permissionError = "You do not have the permission to run this command.",
                requiredRoles = [],
                minArgs = 0,
                maxArgs = null,
                expectedArgs,
                callback
            } = command

            for (const permission of permissions) {
                if (!member.hasPermission(permission)) {
                  message.reply(permissionError)
                  return
                }
              }
      
                      for (const requiredRole of requiredRoles) {
                          const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === requiredRole)
      
                          if (!role || !member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
                              message.reply(`You must have the "${requiredRole}" role to use this command.`)
                              return 
                          }
                      }
      
                      if (arguments.length < minArgs || (
                          maxArgs !== null && arguments.length > maxArgs
                      )) {
                          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                          embed.setTitle(`Incorrect syntax! Use ${prefix}${alias} ${expectedArgs}`)
                          message.reply(embed)
                          return
                      }
      
                      callback(message, arguments, arguments.join(' '), client) 
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you execute this?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `commands`?